# Properly add a sub directory in a project using git subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

**How to properly add a sub directory in a project using git subtree, make changes in it, and update back the main remote with the subtree?**

I have a main repository, that I'd like to add a third-party repository to it.

I've read that one way to do it is using git [sub-tree](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree), expecting it to be managed as a stand-alone repo that you may choose to update/ignore when ever needed - perfect for my use!

**What I've done so far:**

1. I cloned the main repo locally.
2. I then wrote this command to add the remote folder locally to my main project `git subtree add --prefix <my-dir-name> <remote-url> <#commit> --squash`

**What I need help with:**

When I type `git status` the sub-directory I just created isn't tracked for some reason and it won't show me it was added and needs to be pushed. Is that normal? If yes, then how do I track it? I'd like to push it to the remote of the main project.

**What is this sub-directory used for:**

1. It's a node project used to build a file using the project every once in a while, and update its files when needed by the version I choose to update to.
2. My co-workers to download the main repository with the sub-directory in it.

**Extra Question:**

3. If I never want to push to the subdirectory original remote, but only to pull from it and update the code every once in a while, do I ever need to use the `git subtree split` command?

I've read the [git subtree manual](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-man/git-subtree.1.en.html), and 2 guides about the subject, plus watched a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sC1sfoCo5qY), and still I rather asking to be safe than sorry.